# Docker COPY command give 777 access to the copied file

Tags: linux, docker, file-access

In my docker file I have below command:

```
USER gerrit
COPY gerrit-default-config /var/gerrit/etc/gerrit.config
```

Running the image I see that the file access number is 777.
Is it default value? Is there a way to change the access other than running chmod after each COPY?

```
RUN chmod 600 /var/gerrit/etc/gerrit.config
```

Comment: Permission `777` is definitely not the default value. What is the permission of your local file ? `ls -l gerrit-default-config`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The permissions are inherited from your host. If that file is on 777 on your host before copying then you get 777 in the container.

If you don't want 777 here ever, just chmod it to 600 in the host.

Source: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6333

Answer (score 11):

Update 2021: [there's now a flag for `ADD` and `COPY`](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/pull/1492).
(Docker Engine >= 20.10, Docker BuildKit enabled, docker/dockerfile >= 1.3)

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM debian:buster
COPY --chmod=0644 file /path
```

Because file usages are written in the Dockerfile (i.e. which serves as documentation), it makes sense to explicit the permissions in the Dockerfile too, rather than in another file hidden in the CICD process.

FTR Git does not store Unix permissions, only the executable flag.

Comment: It may require Docker BuildKit.

Comment: Please state which version of Docker is required for the `--chmod` flag on `COPY`, I do not see that in the current version's online doc: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

Comment: Updated. As of today [the PR to add this flag to the documentation](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/2941) is still pending.